# Celery task worker not updating in production

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs, production-environment

I have set up a `django` project on an `EC2` instance with `SQS` as broker for `celery`, running through `Supervisord`. The problem started when I updated the parameter arguments for a task. On calling the task, I get an error on `Sentry` which clearly shows that the task is running the old code. How do I update it?

I have tried `supervisorctl restart all` but still there are issues. The strange thing is that for some arguments, the updated code runs while for some it does not.

I checked the logs for the celery worker and it doesn't receive the tasks which give me the error. I am running `-P solo` so there is only one worker (Ran `ps auxww | grep 'celery worker'` to check). Then who else is processing those tasks?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

P.S. I use `RabbitMQ` for local development and it works totally fine

Comment: its not an issue with the queue, celery workers are not properly getting killed  can you do  `supervisorctl stop all `  followed by `supervisorctl start all`

Comment: @JibinMathews Tried that also, still getting the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use the same queue in different environments.